# TensorBoard not launching any graphs

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I have the following code that I execute inside a Jupyter notebook

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 25
display_step = 1

# tf Graph Input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, dims]) 
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, nb_classes])

# Construct (linear) model
with tf.name_scope("model") as scope:
    # Set model weights
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([dims, nb_classes]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nb_classes]))
    activation = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b) # Softmax

    # Add summary ops to collect data
    w_h = tf.summary.histogram("weights_histogram", W)
    b_h = tf.summary.histogram("biases_histograms", b)
    tf.summary.scalar('mean_weights', tf.reduce_mean(W))
    tf.summary.scalar('mean_bias', tf.reduce_mean(b))

# Minimize error using cross entropy
# Note: More name scopes will clean up graph representation
with tf.name_scope("cost_function") as scope:
    cross_entropy = y*tf.log(activation)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(cross_entropy,reduction_indices=1))
    # Create a summary to monitor the cost function
    tf.summary.scalar("cost_function", cost)
    tf.summary.histogram("cost_histogram", cost)

with tf.name_scope("train") as scope:
    # Set the Optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

with tf.name_scope('Accuracy') as scope:
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(activation, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    # Create a summary to monitor the cost function
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

LOGDIR = '/tmp/logistic_logs'
import os, shutil
if os.path.isdir(LOGDIR):
    shutil.rmtree(LOGDIR)
os.mkdir(LOGDIR)

# Plug TensorBoard Visualisation 
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR, graph=tf.get_default_graph())

for var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES):
    print(var.name)

summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
print('Summary Op: ' + summary_op)


# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as session:
    # Initializing the variables
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    cost_epochs = []
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        _, summary, c = session.run(fetches=[optimizer, summary_op, cost], 
                                    feed_dict={x: X_train, y: Y_train})
        cost_epochs.append(c)
        writer.add_summary(summary=summary, global_step=epoch)
        print("accuracy epoch {}:{}".format(epoch, accuracy.eval({x: X_train, y: Y_train})))

    print("Training phase finished")

    #plotting
    plt.plot(range(len(cost_epochs)), cost_epochs, 'o', label='Logistic Regression Training phase')
    plt.ylabel('cost')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    prediction = tf.argmax(activation, 1)
    print(prediction.eval({x: X_test}))


%%bash
tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/logistic_logs
```

When I execute the tensorboard command I do not get any scalars, graphs, etc. It just loads the tensorboard dashboard. For instance for graphs I get: `"No graph definition files were found."`

Comment: Try with the full path instead of using the relative path once. tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/logistic_logs. Looks to be an issue with your current working directory in bash.

Answer (score 0):

I manually created a directory named: `logistic_logs` in the same directory where the Jupyter Notebook is and then ran the following code. This worked for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 25
display_step = 1
dims = 3
nb_classes = 2

tf.reset_default_graph()

# tf Graph Input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, dims]) 
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, nb_classes])

# Construct (linear) model
with tf.name_scope("model") as scope:
    # Set model weights
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([dims, nb_classes]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nb_classes]))
    activation = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b) # Softmax

    # Add summary ops to collect data
    w_h = tf.summary.histogram("weights_histogram", W)
    b_h = tf.summary.histogram("biases_histograms", b)
    tf.summary.scalar('mean_weights', tf.reduce_mean(W))
    tf.summary.scalar('mean_bias', tf.reduce_mean(b))

# Minimize error using cross entropy
# Note: More name scopes will clean up graph representation
with tf.name_scope("cost_function") as scope:
    cross_entropy = y*tf.log(activation)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(cross_entropy,reduction_indices=1))
    # Create a summary to monitor the cost function
    tf.summary.scalar("cost_function", cost)
    tf.summary.histogram("cost_histogram", cost)

with tf.name_scope("train") as scope:
    # Set the Optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

with tf.name_scope('Accuracy') as scope:
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(activation, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    # Create a summary to monitor the cost function
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

# Plug TensorBoard Visualisation 
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("logistic_logs", graph=tf.get_default_graph())

for var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES):
    print(var.name)

summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
print('Summary Op: ' + summary_op)


# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as session:
    # Initializing the variables
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    writer.add_graph(session.graph)
```

Please note that the issue might be that you are not reseting the default graph before building the graph. The default graph is already built when you execute the code the first time, so don't forget to always reset default graph before building it. This line in my code deals with that:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Then, just ran:

```
tensorboard --logdir=logistic_logs/
```